# How to open a new browser tab after async HTTP call in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to open a new tab in browser programmatically in Angular 7. This must be done only after successful HTTP request to third-party service. A browser must understand it as a "trusted" operation. That's mean that open should not be blocked. For example, Chrome calls popup blocker in the case of subscribing on HTTP response in Angular.

PS
Variant with opening new tab before the request is not applicable in my case.

Thank you.